# Shiny table loses centering when placed in iframe

Tags: css, r, iframe, shiny

Here is a Shiny table that is roughly centered in the page. It can be seen [here](https://whatbank.ca/tmp/).

```
library(shiny)
library(reactable)

df <- mtcars[1:4, 1:3]

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Here is a heading"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, align="center"),
    reactableOutput("table"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(df,
              fullWidth = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I link to this Shiny app from from an iframe the centering disappears as can be seen [here](https://img.whatbank.ca/ctr_reactable_tbl_01.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div >
<iframe src="https://whatbank.ca/tmp" width=500; height=1000; style="margin-bottom: 1px;" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

1. How do I maintain the centering when placed in an iframe?
2. Is this, `column(3, align="center"),` the correct way to center the table?

Comment: To center the table I would do `fluidRow(column(12, align="center", reactableOutput("table")))`.

Comment: Yes that works in the example I gave. Unfortunately, you were unable to read my mind and realize what I wanted was a solution for a tabBox that is inside a  ui = dashboardPage(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `width=500` is too small. Try `width="100%"`.